# Unable to export Testing and Training data as TFRecord using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification, google-cloud, tensorflow

While trying to export training (about 700 points) and testing data (about 300 points) as TFRecord, I am getting the following error:
**User memory limit has exceeded**

The code I have written, is similar to the material available online, and is:

```
var band = [ 'B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4','B5','B6','B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11', 'B12'];
var training = cloudFree.select(band).sampleRegions({
    collection: trainFinal,
    properties: ['CrID'],
    scale: 30,
       tileScale: 16
   });

//Exporting Training and Testing datasets

Export.table.toCloudStorage({
     collection:training,
     description:'Training_Export',
     fileNamePrefix: 'trainingTestData',
     bucket: gcs_bucket,
     fileFormat:'TFRecord'
     });
```

Is there any mistake in the above code, or should I reduce the number of points / bands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An out of memory error depends on how much data you're processing. If a lot of data and processing goes into creating cloudFree, you might want to export it as an asset before doing the sampling. That will give you more memory when sampling.

Comment: Hi Daniel, if I need to do this for 15 such images, would you still suggest exporting the images to assets and then carrying out the sampling? Each export to asset takes about 4-5 hours hence making the task laborious

Comment: If it fails when you don't export, I suggest you do. You can run your exports in parallel, so while it takes time, it should finish over night.